# VBA Macro Crashing for When Pasting Range to Table

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm trying to create a macro in which it takes a dynamic number of rows (user inputted) and pastes them into a table in a different sheet. I was having a difficult time searching and finding ways for doing this at first. I have a workaround below that works the first time (it correctly takes the 'raw' range and pastes it into the table) when I run it from VBA but crashes when I press the macro-assigned button right after. My code is below:

```
Sub AddRawData()

Dim count_of_data As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheets("New Input Raw Data").Range("B5", Range("B5").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
count_of_data = rng.Rows.Count

Sheets("Master Data").Select
For x = 1 To count_of_data
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add
Next x
Sheets("New Input Raw Data").Select
rng.Select
rng.Cut
Sheets("Master Data").Select
Range("b65536").End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

I'm stuck at the moment and have tried various work arounds like using ActiveCell.paste or Range.Paste, but run into the same crashing issue. Any suggestions or code corrections would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please share if it is throwing any errors. Or please share what exactly happening? Any Popup, or anything like not responding..

Comment: I have Tried your code in Excel 2010 with limited data. Its working fine. Which version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy the new inserted data from ***New Input Raw Data*** worksheet to the end of existing data in ***Master Data*** sheet, you don't need all the `Select` and most of the lines, you can just run the code below:

```
Sub AddRawData()

Dim rng As Range
Dim sht_NewData As Worksheet
Dim sht_MasterData As Worksheet

Set sht_NewData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New Input Raw Data")
Set sht_MasterData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data")

sht_NewData.Select
Set rng = sht_NewData.Range("B5", Range("B5").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

rng.Copy Destination:=sht_MasterData.Range("B" & sht_MasterData.Cells(sht_MasterData.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1)

End Sub
```